# AWS CVS data pipelining

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and want to do some data pipelining in AWS.

I have a bunch on CSV file stored in S3

Things I want to achieve:

1. I want to union all the CSV files and add the filename to each
   line, the first line needs to be removed for each file before
   unioning the CSVs;
2. Split the filename column by the `_` delimiter;
3. Store this all in a DB after processing.

What is the best/fastest way to achieve this in a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a glue job using pyspark which will get the csv file in df and then you can transform it however you like.

After that you can convert that df to parquet and save that in s3.

Then you can run a glue crawler which will convert the parquet data to table which you can query.

Basically you are doing ETL using glue aws.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried a simple load csv from s3 and save to s3 as parquet. I didn't get any errors but I dont see the new file

Comment: `import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://test-bucket20192019/"]}, format = "csv")
outputGDF = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = inputGDF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://test-bucket20192019/"}, format = "parquet")`

Comment: I did something similar here - https://github.com/sudarshan2906/Csv-to-Parquet-using-AWS-Glue-/tree/master

Comment: Thanks Sudarshan. I was using your script seems to do working. I noticed it generates multiple parquet file, I was expecting one.

Comment: I just ran the job.py file. The only change I made was the file name

Comment: It seems to be only writing four rows per file